# Class implementing interface as method return type in C#

Tags: c#, oop

Is it possible in C# to define return type of a method as some class that additionally implement some interface?

For example, in GTK# application I would like to have a widget to display documents. I would like to provide several implementations of that widget - one based on Gecko, one on Webkit and one, basic,on regular Gtk.TextView. Clearly, all those classes have to inherit from Gtk.Widget (indirectly). I would declare an interface that all those widgets would implement. Last, I would create a factory method that would create appropriate widget, based on eg. available libraries. What type should factory method return?

```
interface IDocumentView {...};

class GeckoDocumentView : Gecko.Webcontrol, IDocumentView {...};

class WebKitDocumentView : WebKit.WebView, IDocumentView {...};

class BasicDocumentView : Gtk.TextView, IDocumentView {...};

class DocumentViewFactory {
    static IDocumentView CreateView () {...};
}
```

What should be return type of DocumentViewFactory.CreateView method? If it's not possible to specify both Gtk.Widget and IDocumentView, should it be:

- Gtk.Widget (base class), which will be later casted to IDocumentView?
- IDocumentView (interface), which will be later casted to Gtk.Widget?

**EDIT** - can interface force inheriting from specific base class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to keep **platform code** (which GTK# falls under) out of **my code** as much as possible.

Given that, I would prefer to return `IDocumentView`.

This way, your code will use the `IDocumentView` interface and your platform plumbing code can use the `Gtk.*` classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx).